# What will be the command to generate app bundle in flutter with SkSL warmup

Tags: flutter, performance, shader, jank

Using flutter SkSL warmup you can generate apk's using following command
`flutter run --profile --cache-sksl` My Question is the same command will be used for build app bundle for android `flutter build appbundle --cache-sksl`?

If anyone has some knowledge on this kindly guid me as I have never build app bundle with Sksl Warmup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first run on command line app and testing all screen to cach junk:

```
flutter run  --profile --cache-sksl --purge-persistent-cache
```

It is better to do it on real device.
After testing all screen, you have to : Press M at the command line you running  the command below. It will show that it wrote :

```
Wrote SkSL data to ......\flutter_01.sksl.json.
```

Now you can use flutter_01.sksl.json for building :

```
flutter build appbundle --bundle-sksl-path flutter_01.sksl.json
```